# Am I using JavaScript classes as they should?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I'm trying to do a Chrome plugin, does some web scraping and shows the info. I'm pretty new to programming and I usually do everything with functions, this is my first try with classes. I have this code that works, I just want to know if I did implement it as it should.
The news and deals method are doing the same things as quote method, but different source, so i cut it out so wont be that much code.
What can I improve about this code?
In code when I use `Plugin.random` looks weird, is that how it's used? I tried `this.random` and throws an error.

```
class Plugin {
    static random(min, max) {
        return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    }
    get deals(){
        return this.getDeals();
    }
    get news(){
        return this.getNews();
    }
    get quote(){
        return this.getQuote();
    }
    getDeals() {
        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send();
    }
    getNews() {
        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send();
    }
    getQuote() {
        for(let i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
            let page = Math.round(Plugin.random(1, 22));
            if (page !== 17) {
                var url = 'https://www.somesite.com?page=' + page;
                break;
            }
        }
        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onload = function(event) {
        let parser = new DOMParser();
        let xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(request.response,"text/html");
        for(let i = 25; i > 0; i--) {
            let nr = Math.round(Plugin.random(1, 24));
           if(xmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("quoteText")[nr].innerHTML.length < 600) {
                var quote = xmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("quoteText")[nr].innerHTML.split('"')[0].split('<br>')[0];
                let title = xmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("quoteText")[nr].getElementsByClassName("authorOrTitle")[0].innerHTML;
              break;
           }
        }
        document.getElementById('beforeand').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',quote.substr(8).slice(0, -4) + '<br><p class="author">' + title + '</p>');
        };
        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send();
    }
}

const test = new Plugin();
test.quote;
test.news;
test.deals;
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question belongs on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Your getNews will probably have some issues since url is not defined as far as I can see :-). I also don't understand why you'd make these shorthand getters to actually call a webrequest and they are not even returning anything.

So I think you are kind of using classes correctly, your code is just weird.

Comment: `request` is not in scope of `getDeals` or `getNews`, not sure what you're trying to do there. Also, there's not much point to having getter methods that simply call other methods externally visible on the class.

Comment: I didn't even know about codereview, this is great! :)

Comment: @MathijsSegers, those getters are just like getQuote, I just removed the code so wont be that long, I said that already. So if getQuote is good, those are as well, cause they're the same, just different source for XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Same answer for @CertainPerformance

Comment: @Alex Then still it doesn't return anything, so you've made a getter which doesn't return data. I really suggest you to go to code review.

Anyway what I meant is you use the actual JS getters e.g. get quote. Whilst also having a method getQuote. That seems silly since they're both publicly accessible. When you use those getter methods (`get someVar`). You expect them to actually return a value, like a class property. This is however not limited to javascript.

Comment: @MathijsSegers, so if I return `document.getElementById('beforeand').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',quote.substr(8).slice(0, -4) + '<br><p class="author">' + title + '</p>');` would be fine? Thing is I just want to insert some html, not actually return some value.

Comment: Just don't use getters for actions

Comment: @MathijsSegers, ok, what should I use then?